# Fish and Meat only an issue until year 5000?

Tags: meat, fish

The Aishel Avraham - Rav Avraham M’Butchach - says that the the decree not to eat meat and fish together was only made until the year 5000, but no longer applicable after that. Where does he write that? (And do contemporary Poskim use that as an additional factor to be lenient? I've only seen Poskim mention the Magen Avraham 173:1 as a potential factor in these kinds of questions)

Comment: There are two separate questions: is it [still] dangerous and is it rabbinically prohibited anyway? This opinion would only be useful in conjunction with an opinion that it is not dangerous. It couldn't be an additional factor above the Magen Avraham.

Comment: How do you know he says this that you ask where he did?

Answer (score 5):

I found it quoted in Shemiras Haguf V’HanefeshThe Mahashdam Chelek Daled Siman 124 in the name Sefer Hakana after the Year 5000 [image]

Comment: Did the Aishel Avraham say anything about this?

Comment: Will have to take a in-depth look. Just saw that opinion at the moment regarding the 5000

Comment: This isn't exactly the OP's claim. This says the danger was removed [by God?] after 5k. The OP claimed the rabbinic prohibition to eat them together expired.

Comment: @Robev I couldn’t find any reference to Eshel Avraham

Comment: What I find interesting as the 5000yr rule because the Cherem of Rabbainu Gershom used it but was kept indefinitely. I wonder why they picked this number?